# Margin cost problem

Tags: derivatives

Cost is in dollars and x is the number of units. Find the marginal cost functions MC for the given cost function.
C = 700 + 22x + 6x^3
MC =

first I tried 22+12x^2 but i just realized you bring down the exponential power down and subtract it by one then which. igot 22+9x^2 but its wrong

how come 22+9x^2 is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Let´s say you have a polynomial function $f_n(x)=a_n\cdot   x^n + a_{n-1}\cdot  x^{n-1} + \dotsb + a_2 x^2 + a_1 \cdot  x +   a_0$, then the derivative w.r.t. $x$ is

$$f_n'(x)=a_n \cdot  n\cdot  x^{n-1} +    a_{n-1}\cdot(n-1)\cdot  x^{n-1} + \dotsb + a_2\cdot 2\cdot x^{2-1} + a_1  $$

$$f_n'(x)=a_n \cdot  n\cdot  x^{n-1} +    a_{n-1}\cdot(n-1)\cdot  x^{n-1} + \dotsb + a_2\cdot 2\cdot x + a_1  $$

In your case it is $n=3, a_3=6, a_2=0, a_1=22$ and $a_0=700$

$$f_3(x)=C(x)= a_3 \cdot x^3+a_2 \cdot x^2 + a_1 \cdot  x +   a_0=6 \cdot x^3 +   22\cdot  x +   700$$

And therefore the derivative w.r.t $x$ is

$$f_3'(x)=C'(x)=   a_{3}\cdot 3\cdot  x^{2} +  a_2\cdot 2\cdot x + a_1=6 \cdot 3\cdot  x^2 +   22=18 \cdot  x^2 +   22$$

I guess that you had a miscalculation at $6\cdot 3=18\neq 9$